# How to make kendoDatePicker popup

Tags: kendo-datepicker

I have two kendo date pickers. I want to be able to make the other one popup after a date is selected on the first one. Here is my code snippet:

```
      $(this.oParentDiv.find('.datePicker')).kendoDatePicker({
            format: "yyyy-MM-dd",
            change: function (e) {
              if (e.sender.element.context.className.indexOf("fromDate") != -1) {
                $(".toDate").val(moment(this._value).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
               //Code to make toDate popup comes here
              }
            }
          });
```

How can I make the toDate popup after a date has been selected in the fromDate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open method on date picker instances. You can call it like this from within your change function after you set the second picker's value:

```
$(".toDate").data("kendoDatePicker").open();
```